# Send data between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I have two activities each one hold one fragment.
I sent the data(simple string) between the first fragmrnt to the second activity, but I cant send it from the activity to the second fragment.
What am I doing wrong?

This is the activity that get the data:

```
public class DiaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        manager.beginTransaction().add(new EditDiaryFragment(), "tag").commit();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
// get the data and pass it to the fradment... not working :(
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
    String diary = intent.getStringExtra("diary");

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("date", date);
    bundle.putString("diary", diary);

    EditDiaryFragment editDiaryFragment = new EditDiaryFragment();
    editDiaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
}


}
```

And this is the fragment who need to get the data:

```
public class EditDiaryFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText diaryEditText;
private Button diarySaveButton;
private TextView diaryDateText;
private String today;
private ShvizoutDBHelper helper;
private StringBuffer buffer;


public EditDiaryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    helper = new ShvizoutDBHelper(getContext());


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_diary, container, false);
    diaryDateText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.diaryDateText);
    diarySaveButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.diarySaveButton);
    diaryEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.diaryEditText);

    diarySaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        String bDate = bundle.getString("date");
        String bDiary = bundle.getString("diary");

        diaryDateText.setText(bDate);
        diaryEditText.setText(bDiary);
    }

    return v;
}


}
```

Thank!!

Comment: Try to run in the debug mode to see where the data gets lost. If all else fails, use EventBus.

Comment: obviously you have two instances of `EditDiaryFragment` one with argument and second without ... and you does nothing with the one with arguments

Comment: mm... how can I fix it? replace the fragment with the manager?

Comment: Ok. my mistake. I have the fragment loaded in the Xml. and I cant do setArguments.
I deleted the fragment from the Xml, change the code a litel. amd it is working now.
thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

You need to add same EditDiaryFragment instance to your activity after adding your bundles:

```
EditDiaryFragment editDiaryFragment = new EditDiaryFragment();
editDiaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(editDiaryFragment, "tag").commit();
```